# why puts() not printing anything

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
//#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char mystr[20],rev[20];
int i,c=0;
cout<<"Enter a String: ";
gets(mystr);
for (i=0;mystr[i]!='\0';i++);
for (int j=i;j>=0;j--)
{
    rev[c]=mystr[j];
    c++;    
}
cout<<"Reverse is: ";
puts(rev);
return 0;
}
```

**Why puts() not printing anything?**
if i use *for loop* to print string *rev* output is correct but why **puts** is not giving correct output?

Comment: `<iostream>` and `gets()`? C++ and `char[]`? Really? What happened to `std::string mystr; std::getline( cin, mystr );`?

Comment: `gets` is unsafe. Don't use it. Not even in C.

Comment: To elaborate on my first-glance comment: **This is not C++.** Aside from using `cout` instead of `puts()` in two places, this is plain C. So either this question is mis-tagged, or you're using the world's worst C++ tutorial ever. (Also, whitespaces...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because first symbol of `rev` is `\0` after your reverse operation, and `puts` considers a string as a null-terminated. So, it sees that first byte is null and stops immediately.

You may modify your loops this way:

```
for (i = 0; mystr[i] != '\0'; i++);
rev[i] = '\0';
for (int j = i-1; j>=0; j--)
{
    rev[c] = mystr[j];
    c++;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the `rev` array is a local and it is not initialized; this means the resulting string is not guaranteed to have the needed terminating `\0`.

You can fix that adding a `rev[c]='\0'` before calling `puts`.

Also you need to start from the character **before** the `\0` in the input string, otherwise the output will start with a `'\0'` and the `puts` function will stop right there.

Answer (score 0):

puts() writes the \0 (null) terminated string to the standard output (stdout) and appends a newline character ('\n'). As rev is having the \0 char at 0th position, puts() prints nothing.

you can use below code to revers a char array.

```
int lenth = strlen(mystr);
int pos = lenth-1;   // one posation before \0 char
int i = 0
for (; i <= pos; i++)
{
    rev[i] = mystr[pos-i];
}
rev[i] = '\0';
```

or

```
int lenth = strlen(mystr);
int start = 0;
int end = lenth-1;      // one posation before \0 char
for (; start < end; start++, end--)
{
    char t;
    t = mystr[start];
    mystr[start] = mystr[end];
    mystr[end] = t;
}
```

Hope it helps!